# UIView to UIViewController communication via protocol not working

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, communication, hittest

maybe I am missing something really fundamental here, but after staring at the code for an hour or so, my brain is going trough cycles and I would appreciate a fresh glance at this problem.

I have the following `UIView`:

```
import UIKit

protocol DetailViewWillShowUpDelegate {
    func sendDetailOpened(_ openedBool: Bool)
}

class locationXIBController: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var loationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var vsedniOteviraciDobaLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prijmajiKartyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailViewButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundViewButton: UIButton!

    let openedBool = true
    var detailViewWillShowUpDelegate: DetailViewWillShowUpDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    @IBAction func vecerkaDetailButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        detailViewWillShowUpDelegate?.sendDetailOpened(openedBool)
        print("pressed")
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if let result = detailViewButtonOutlet.hitTest(convert(point, to: detailViewButtonOutlet), with: event) {
            return result
        }
        return backgroundViewButton.hitTest(convert(point, to: backgroundViewButton), with: event)
    }

}
```

Now the problem is, that when I call/press the `vecerkaDetailButtonPressed` function I get "pressed" output in the console but the protocol for some reason doesn't go trough.

The other side looks like this (stripped for simplicity):

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationXIB = locationXIBController()
    let isVecerkaDetailOpened = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       locationXIB.detailViewWillShowUpDelegate = self
    }



extension MapViewController: DetailViewWillShowUpDelegate {
    func sendDetailOpened(_ openedBool: Bool) {
        isVecerkaDetailOpened = openedBool
        print("success")
    }
}
```

I know the protocol value at the moment of execution is nil. As I said, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So does `detailViewWillShowUpDelegate` actually point at anything, or is it nil?

Comment: @Caleb I just tried debugging and it is actually `nil`

Comment: Where are you adding the `locationXIB` to your `MapViewController`?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Thanks for the reply: I am not, the locationXIBController is used as a custom `MKAnnotation` class which is used in a custom `MKAnnotationView` class, however I need to somehow connect the instance of the `locationXIBController` which is being invoked by tapping on one map annotation and send infromation from this `locationXIBController` class to the `MapViewController`, your question (a very good one) is actually the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: If it is being used as an annotation, then you will need to set the delegate where you add it as an annotation view. Can you show that code

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the reply, great point: There are 3 classes figuring in this problem: one of type `MKAnnotation` (the `locationXIBController` ) then a custom `MKAnnotationView` class where the annotation is being created and then the `MapViewController`, the annotation is created in the annotationView class however I need to set the delegate to MapViewController, any idea? Thanks

Comment: Presumably the view for annotation method in in the mapview controller, so set the view's delegate to `self`

Comment: @Paulw11 I think you mean like this:
      `var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "reuseID")
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = LocationInformationAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "reuseID")
            locationXIB.detailViewWillShowUpDelegate = self
        } else { `

I already tried that before with no result

Comment: That is the correct approach but you need `annotationView.delegate = self`  You need to set the delegate on the actual annotation view, not some property that isn't even added to the map

Comment: @Paulw11 But the annotation view doesn't have a delegate, only `LocationXIBController` (annotation) and `MapViewController`

Comment: Your `LocationInformationAnnotationView` needs to have a delegate property so that it can pass messages to your `MapViewController`.  If the `LocationInformationAnnotationView` contains the `LocationXIBController` then the annotation view should set itself as the views delegate and pass upstream to *its* delegate (the map view controller)

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks it was a brilliant idea! Finally managed it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the credit of @Paulw11

I finally managed to get it working by communicating like so:

step 1) 1:1 communication via protocol between MKAnnotation and MKAnnotationView

step 2) 1:1 communication via protocol between MKAnnotationView and MapViewController passing the same data

Finally works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, a couple of naming convention issues:

The name `locationXIBController` is a bad choice for a `UIView` object. It is a view object, not a controller object.

Second, class names in Swift should start with an upper-case letter. So `LocationXIBView` would be a much better name for that view class.

Next, your code

```
let locationXIB = locationXIBController()
```

...is wrong. That creates a brand-new instance of your locationXIBController class that you never install in your view hierarchy. You should make that line an IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var locationXIB: locationXIBController!
```

And then you should control-drag from the `locationXIBController` in your StoryBoard onto the outlet in your view controller. That will cause Interface Builder to connect the outlet.

Now when you run your program the variable `locationXIB` will be connected to the `locationXIBController` view from your storyboard/XIB when it's loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I cannot drag and link the view with MapViewController because the locationXIB.xib is a standalone xib file, not in the storyboard. So how would I go about this with the setup as I have it?

Comment: You can still connect links to XIBs. It's been a while since I've done it, but I seem to remember that you need to make the owning class for the XIB match the view controller you're connecting to.

Comment: The thing is that the XIB already has an owning class where other code is being executed which cant be done from the MapViewController and I dont think you can connect the XIB file to 2 different classes.

Comment: In the storyboard scene that is being controlled by `MapViewController` is there a view that is standing in for the `locationXIBController`? If so _that_ is what you need to connect to the `locationXIB` outlet Duncan mentions.If not, how does the `locationXIBController` instance get onscreen?

Comment: @theMikeSwan There is not, the whole process is done programatically

Comment: Basically you need to make sure that the same instance that is added to the screen is the one you set the delegate on. Perhaps move the code to assign the delegate to the same place that you add the view to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @Duncan C, you might check whether you need `super.viewDidLoad()` at the top of the `viewDidLoad()` method in the `MapViewController` class? Not doing that can lead to quirky things in your app.

Answer (score 1):

I asked:

> So does detailViewWillShowUpDelegate actually point at anything, or is it nil?

And you replied:

> I just tried debugging and it is actually nil

So that's the problem... you need to set `detailViewWillShowUpDelegate` to point to a valid delegate object. This is often done in the .xib file or storyboard, and sometimes people forget to make that connection, so check there if it makes sense. Else you'll just need to get a reference to the delegate at some point before the code in question can run and set it up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Caleb, here is the problem: the XIB file is already connected to a class, so I cannot really link it into the MapViewController, I tried instantiating it with `locationXIB = UINib(nibName: "locationXIB", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! LocationXIBView` to no result. I am running out of ideas as to how to instantiate / connect to the existing instance of the `LocationXIBController`

Comment: See how you're passing `nil` for the owner parameter? Any connections in the .xib that's connected to File's Owner will be nil if you do that. You do have to set the *class* of File's Owner in the .xib, but that just let's Xcode know what can be connected to the File's Owner proxy... you still have to pass in an actual object of that type when you load the .xib. And since the file's owner is often a view controller that acts as delegate to some of the views, I wouldn't be surprised if this is the root of your problem.

Comment: The .xib is connected to the `LocationXIBContoller` class (this class is the owner), not the `MapViewController`, but the delegate needs to be set to the `MapViewController`, however the file cannot have 2 owners right

Comment: Then you'll need to set the delegate after you load the objects in the .xib. And again, passing `nil` for the file's owner is likely not the right thing to do, especially if you've bothered to set the type of the File's Owner proxy.

Comment: But the .xib does have an owner, it is `LocationXIBController` - that is the file owner. However I need to link it with `MapViewController` which is a completely different class and this class is not the owner of the .xib file.

Comment: The result of your call to `instantiate(withOwner:options)` is an array of the top-level objects in the .xib; once you have that, you can further configure any of the objects in that array, including setting their delegate objects, etc.